# C#: Splicing array

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's say I have a `long[]` called `IDs` with a few elements in the array.

What's the easiest way to splice into/insert a new element at a given index?

Right now I'm doing this, and I don't think it's optimal:

```
long[] IDs = ...;

var IDsList = IDs.ToList();
IDsList.Insert(newId, indexToInsertAt);

IDs = IDsList.ToArray();
```

There's nothing built-in into the `Array` class?! This strikes me as very odd, coming from the JavaScript world of `[].splice()`.

Comment: Any reason you are using an array over a List<T>?

Comment: It struck me as odd too having come from PHP but what you have is what I'd use in C#

Comment: There's nothing built into the Array class because this is what the List<T> class is for

Answer (score 11):

Use a `List<long>` instead of the array since you're needing to make inserts.

Comment: Hmm, apparently this wasn't clear: the argument that I have to work with (defined by an interface) is long[].

Comment: @AgileMeansDoAsLittleAsPossible: Wait, are you the OP? Seems you have multiple identities...

Comment: Hmm, an interface cannot specify fields.  You cannot resize an array passed as a method argument unless it is declared *ref*.

Answer (score 6):

It might seem a bit odd, but probably it was left out to prevent developers from writing code with bad performance too easily. (If you're inserting a new item in the middle, you probably want a resizable collection like `List<T>`.) The only way to "insert" into a fixed-size collection like an `Array` is to copy the collection's contents into a *new* collection and put the item *there*. Obviously this is not the best idea if you're performing a lot of insertions.

If the use of a `T[]` array is outside your control, and insertion is necessary, copying the array yourself is at least preferable to the code you have, as it saves you *two* costly operations: a copy and an insertion, which requires that potentially many elements be "shifted" by one index. (Your current solution copies the contents of the `long[]` into a `List<long>`, then inserts an item into that `List<long>`, *then* copies that `List<long>` *back* into a new `long[]`.)

In this case (the choice of a `T[]` is not negotiable), you might consider an extension method to do what I just described above. This way at least you have a reusable piece of code for scenarios when you *do* need this behavior. Something like:

```
public static class ArrayHelper
{
    public static T[] Insert<T>(this T[] source, int index, T item)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }

        if (index < 0 || index > source.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
        }

        // Allocate a new array with enough space for one more item.
        T[] result = new T[source.Length + 1];

        // Copy all elements before the insertion point.
        for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
        {
            result[i] = source[i];
        }

        // Insert the new value.
        result[index] = item;

        // Copy all elements after the insertion point.
        for (int i = index; i < source.Length; ++i)
        {
            result[i + 1] = source[i];
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Notice that the above is considerably more efficient than what you have now, as it only needs to perform the equivalent of a full array copy *one* time (not twice), and it also doesn't require any intermediate "shifting" of elements.

Usage:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 2, 3, 4 };
numbers = numbers.Insert(0, 1);

foreach (int number in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Having to do something similar, here's what I've come up with, similar to Dan Tao's:

```
T[] newArr = new T[oldArr.Length+1];

//copy first part of the array, starting with newArr[0] <- oldArr[0], up to the insertion point
System.Array.Copy(oldArr, 0, newArr, 0, insertIndex, insertIndex);

//insert new element
newArr[insertIndex] = spliceElem;

//copy the rest of the array, from newArr[insert+1] <- oldArr[insert] to the end
System.Array.Copy(oldArr, insertIndex, newArr, insertIndex + 1, oldArr.Length-insertIndex);
return newArr;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try with

```
IDs.SetValue(newId, indexToInsertAt);
```

[More here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk3bwkb0.aspx)

Comment: But I'm with Aaron and Tim Robinson, use a List<T> and problem solved.

Comment: That doesn't insert an item, but rather replaces an item.  If that's all he wanted to do, he would write `IDs[indexToInsertAt] = newId`.